# oracle select binded with an array

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

Have a very simple query which perfectly works on oracle db side, but trying to implement it using .net and have following issues below, here's code example:

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand
{
    CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID IN (:1)"
};

cmd.ArrayBindCount = values.Length; // an array of integers boxed to object[]

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
    {
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array,
        Value = values // object array
    });

var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

Using this approach I've an exception - `Invalid parameter binding`
If I would replace `OracleDbType` to `OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal` then I've following exception - `ORA-03146: invalid buffer length for TTC field`.

Help me please to identify what I'm missing here?

Comment: Can u ensure that your values array is an array of integers?

Comment: @YasinARLI Did that before creating post here, so I've also tried to pass directly an array of integers, for ex, 5 values and 5 as count I've specified inside ArrayBindCount, same issues as it mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Help me please to identify what I'm missing here?

```sql
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Will work.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID IN ( :bind_variable_containing_collection_type )
```

Will not work because:

1. A bind variable contains a single value (regardless of whether that single value is a scalar or a UDT containing an array) and the `IN` clause will compare the left-operand with each of the right-operands to see if they are equal; since there is only a single value in the `IN` clause you are checking that a number is equal to an array which will result in a syntax error as they are not the same data types (and if it could work, which it doesn't, then a number value is never going to be equal to an array value regardless of whether that number is a member of the array).
2. C# does not support passing arrays to Oracle. You can pass an associative array but, for some unknown reason, it does not support non-associative arrays.
3. In Oracle, associative arrays are a PL/SQL data type which means that they can be used in a PL/SQL function, procedure or anonymous block but cannot be used in an SQL query.

What you would need to do is pass a PL/SQL associative array to some PL/SQL code that converts the associative array to a non-associative array and then use that in the query.

For examples of the Oracle side of passing PL/SQL associative arrays, see [How to use associative array in "where in" clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74608092/1509264) or [pass integer array to oracle procedure by c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50485813/1509264).

Comment: But if you tried to execute for ex. from datagrip this query and for some reason it would work`SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID IN ( : bind_variable_containing_collection_type )`  so I cannot be agreed with the 1st point, what about the 2nd point it also support non-associate array for the ex. when you tried to use bulk update or create.

Comment: @semperfi From an Oracle point-of-view, a bind variable is always a single value and what I have said is correct. If you have an SQL driver that transforms your statement `WHERE id IN (:array)` to `WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)` before it transmits it to the database then Oracle will only see the statement it receives which contains multiple bind parameters (each of which is a scalar value) but that would be a function of your SQL driver (and since your question does not state any driver details we cannot comment on that).